# Google Cloud Run and JSON in ENV variables

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am deploying a small Node.js app that uses [`config`](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config). `NODE_CONFIG` is read and used to supersede any local configuration. This is handy when deploying a service with secrets because the configuration can be injected from the outside.

When trying to achieve this with Google Cloud Run and the CLI, I am getting an escape error. Apparently only dictionaries are supported by the CLI.

Is there a better way to pass `JSON` content through env variables?

```
gcloud run deploy pr-$PULL_REQUEST \
  --platform=managed \
  --revision-suffix=$revision \
  --region us-central1 \
  --set-env-vars="NODE_ENV=development,NODE_CONFIG='$json'" \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --image gcr.io/...
```

Comment: One thought ... maybe pass the name of an object stored in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) that can then have its content retrieved at runtime?  If not GCS then some other external storage medium such as a database?

Comment: Let's assume I don't own the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple environment variables and you insist on listing environment variables on `gcloud` CLI (instead of writing Service object in YAML + using `gcloud alpha run services replace`), you can simply repeat `--set-env-vars`:

```sh
gcloud run deploy \
  --set-env-vars="A=B" \
  --set-env-vars="C=D" \
  --image=gcr.io/cloudrun/hello
```

Here you can simply do `"KEY=$value"` with surrounding quotes included.

Quoting the value 1) prevents the argument from splitting in case `$value` contains spaces, and 2) escapes quotes inside `$value`  which you will have because you have a json value.

---

#### Example

```
json='{"hello":"world"}'

gcloud run deploy foo \
  --set-env-vars="A=$json" \
  --set-env-vars="C=D" \
  --image=gcr.io/cloudrun/hello
```

`gcloud run services describe [...]` output:

```
  Env vars:
    A                {"hello":"world"}
    C                D
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it doesn't work with the CLI. When you set a comma between 2 values, it doesn't work.

You can use the @Kolban solution where you create a file in GCS and your only reference this file in your EnvVar. But this solution imply to update your code for getting and reading the file from Cloud Storage (more role, more deployment to perform). But it works, I use this mode for passing SQL Queries to my Cloud Run services, until now, it was the only solution!

However, there is a new beta solution, available since 2 weeks: you can use the [`services replace` feature](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/services/replace). This feature allows you to provide only a yaml file for describing your service. Of course, this YAML is compliant with knative API, and thereby, standard.

I tested with JSON and it works, but it imply some change in your deployment process (create the YAML file with the image and the env vars). First, create a minimal YAML file (named, for example: `jsonenv.yaml`)

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  #Name of the service
  name: jsonenv
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: NODE_CONFIG
          value: '{"1":"2","3":"4"}'
        image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/CONTAINER_NAME
```

Then use this command

```
gcloud beta run services replace jsonenv.yaml --platform managed --region WHERE_YOU_WANT
```

That works. Hope this solve your issue.

**EDIT**

For naming your revision, you can add the `metadata.name` in the `template` like this:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  #Name of the service
  name: jsonenv 
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      #Name of the revision
      name: my-revision-name
    spec:
      containers:
```

however, you can't manage the IAM role with this command. Thereby, the `--allow-unauthenticated` can't be used with the replace. You have to set this authorization manually

```
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding jsonenv \
    --member="allUsers" \
    --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

***Note***: You have to do this only once when you deploy the service at the first time, not at each deployment of revision

Comment: Is there a way to pass the YAML on deploy instead of revision?

Comment: This method does not support naming a revision nor --allow-unauthenticated

Comment: @kilianc You can name your revision, but you can't use the allow-unauthenticated. I updated my answer with these information